# How to store object in GraphQL cache in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, graphql

Here in my code I have some value in state 'logTicketDetails' which is object and inside that object there are four arrays . I am getting that value now , in my code I am trying to store that inteir object 'logTicketDetails' in GraphQL object , I have written my code below . But I am getting error .
Please help me how can I store full object in cache .

logTicketDetails value is below

```
    {ticketTypes: Array(3), preferredLanguages: Array(4), responseMediums: Array(2),
```

troubleTicketPriority: Array(3)}

```
// below is logTicketDetails value which is there in state 

    {ticketTypes: Array(3), preferredLanguages: Array(4), responseMediums: Array(2), troubleTicketPriority: Array(3)}
    preferredLanguages: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
    responseMediums: (2) [{…}, {…}]
    ticketTypes: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
    troubleTicketPriority: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
```

// this is my cache query

```
export const LOG_TICKET_DETAILS= gql`
query logTicketDetails {
    logTicketDetails {
     
    }
  }
`
;
```

// Here I am writing to cache

```
 await writeToCache(this,
        LOG_TICKET_DETAILS,
        {
          logTicketDetails : this.state.logTicketDetails,
        }
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

Each "depth level" [of data stored in apollo cache] requires type def (defined structure/sub field types, `__typename` value[-s]) and unique key (usually `id`/`_id`, can be customized per type).

You can store unknown (not to be normalized) structures using **"custom json scalar"** (read docs/tutorials for details). Top level still requires unique key (id, timestamp) - you can add it (decorate entry) after fetching, before cache write.